# What Fertilizer should I use on an Autumn Blaze Maple

Tags: tree-care, maple

I need help finding out what is the best fertilizer for [Acer x freemanii 'Jeffersred' Autumn Blaze®](https://www.chicagobotanic.org/plantinfo/tree_alternatives/autumn_blaze_maple). I was told they need iron, but can't confirm that on the internet.

There is some online info [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/maple/growing-maple-trees.htm), [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/fertilizer-spikes-maple-trees-48024.html), and [there](https://www.ehow.com/how_7669878_fertilize-autumn-blaze-maple-tree.html) though. But I don't seem to be able to find an appropriate credible answer to my question.

Comment: Hi, Linda! Depending on their age, health, soil, climate and previous fertilization, plants have different needs. You can edit your question to include as much details as you know and the members of this community will be able to give you the best advice. Uploading a picture would be even better, if you have the possibility to do it. And by the way, welcome to the site! I hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: They only need iron if your soil isn't neutral to acid in ph, they don't appreciate limey soils. How long have you had this plant and what part of the world are you in? Are you experiencing some problem with the tree?

Comment: What have you used for fertilizer for your tree?  How long ago did you plant this tree, was it in a pot or was it balled and burlapped?  Did you plant this tree?  If so, did you amend the soil (hope not)?  Don't worry about iron.  Your tree, all plants, need a balanced fertilizer.  Please try to get a pH reading of your soil.  How big is your tree?  Where is it you live?